# NTFS properties not available in exFAT

Tags: windows-8, ntfs, exfat

I've been trying to find a list of file/folder properties that are available in NTFS but NOT available in exFAT. The reason I want to know this is because I'm trying to copy a few files from a NTFS drive to an exFAT drive, and I get a warning that says something like "certain properties for this file cannot be copied," but doesn't tell me which ones. This happens on a few video files, and a few *.eml files.

It'd be nice to know what I'm losing...

Answer (score 1):

Well, usually you'd get that error when you have files with custom Access Control Lists configured, or on encrypted or compressed files when moving to fat32. As far as I know, exfat doesn't support those features either so that'd be my guess.